# How to read the stdout of a killed process in Rust?

Tags: rust, stdout, child-process, kill-process

I have a function which should be able to, given a command, a timeout and an input, return the stdout, the stderr, and status (ok or timeout) and the time elapsed to run the command.

The prompted commands are used to get the output of a program with a given input. For example, it can be `node index.js` or `python main.py` (`Command::new("node").arg("index.js")`).

I currently use the [wait-timeout](https://crates.io/crates/wait-timeout) crate, to limit the child process timeout, and `Stdio::piped()` to handle the input and ouput pipes.

I have currently the following code:

```rs
fn exec(mut command: Command, input: &String, time_limit: &f64) -> Result<RunOutput, String> {

    command
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .stderr(Stdio::piped());

    let mut child = match command.spawn() {
        Ok(value) => value,
        Err(err) => {
            let mut message = String::from("Failed to create process: ");
            message.push_str(&err.to_string());

            return Err(message);
        }
    };

    drop(command);

    let mut stdin = child.stdin.take().unwrap();
    stdin
        .write_all(input.as_bytes())
        .expect("Failed to write to stdin");
    stdin.flush().expect("Cannot flush stdin");
    drop(stdin);

    let mut stdout = child.stdout.take().unwrap();
    let mut stderr = child.stderr.take().unwrap();

    let start = Instant::now();
    let secs = Duration::from_secs_f64(*time_limit);

    if child.wait_timeout(secs).unwrap().is_some() {
        let time_elapsed = start.elapsed().as_millis();

        let mut stdout_vec: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
        let mut stderr_vec: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();

        stdout.read_to_end(&mut stdout_vec).expect("Unable to read stdout");
        stderr.read_to_end(&mut stderr_vec).expect("Unable to read stderr");
        

        return Ok(
            RunOutput {
                status: RunStatus::Ok,
                time: time_elapsed,
                stdout: String::from_utf8_lossy(&stdout_vec).to_string(),
                stderr: String::from_utf8_lossy(&stderr_vec).to_string()
            }
        );
    } else {
        let time_elapsed = start.elapsed().as_millis();

        child.kill().unwrap();
        child.wait().unwrap();
        drop(child);

        
        let mut stdout_vec: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
        let mut stderr_vec: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();

        stdout.read_to_end(&mut stdout_vec).expect("Unable to read stdout");
        stderr.read_to_end(&mut stderr_vec).expect("Unable to read stderr");

        return Ok(
            RunOutput {
                status: RunStatus::TimeOut,
                time: time_elapsed,
                stdout: String::from_utf8_lossy(&stdout_vec).to_string(),
                stderr: String::from_utf8_lossy(&stderr_vec).to_string()
            }
        );
    }
}
```

When the child exits before the timeout, everything works fine. However it seems there is in some cases a deadlock which is blocking the process if the command takes too much time.
Moreover, it depends on the command too. When it is a `node` command, it always works, but when calling `python` and killing the child process it blocks the main thread in some cases.

From what I have seen for now, the process blocks when calling `stdout.read_to_end()`, but I don't know what could be the reason.

Edit: the blocking only occurs when the stdout is empty

Comment: Note that `stdin.write_all(input.as_bytes())` will block if the subprocess does not accept any more input, e.g. because the subprocess is blocked while trying to write to it's `stdout`. Since noone is listening, the `stdout` may fill until it blocks, deadlocking both processes (which is ultimately resolved by killing the subprocess on timeout). You need to either use threads or async to simultaneously read and write stdin/stdout for data that may be larger than one "unit of buffering" (platform-dependent)